# using utf8toInt on a dataframe

Tags: r

Very new to R.  I'm trying to use utf8toInt against a dataframe.
I want to scan the data frame for the Int value of 101 (e) and replace it with 69 (E).

My issue here is how to run through each value in the dataframe and execute the utf8ToInt function.
{`

> #### Build out UTF fuction here
>
> a <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "black")
>   b<- c("blue", "yellow", "red", "pink")
>   c<- c("white", "black", "red", "blue")
>
> df = data.frame(a,b,c)
>
> df
>          a     b     c
>   1    red   blue white
>   2   blue yellow black
>   3 yellow    red   red
>   4  black   pink  blue
>
> ### When trying to run against a single value
>
> utf8ToInt(df[1])
>   Error in utf8ToInt(df[1]) : argument must be a character vector of length 1
>
> '}

Comment: try `lapply(df[[1]],utf8ToInt)`

Comment: > lapply(df[[1]],utf8ToInt)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument must be a character vector of length 1
>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never use `c` as variable name since `c()` is also a function.

```
a <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "black");b<- c("blue", "yellow", "red", "pink");c1<- c("white", "black", "red", "blue")
```

note the `stringsAsFactors = F` part.

```
df = data.frame(a,b,c1,stringsAsFactors = F)

lapply(df[[1]],utf8ToInt)
```

result

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 114 101 100
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  98 108 117 101
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 121 101 108 108 111 119
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  98 108  97  99 107
```

Side note: The reason why it did not work is because `factor` variables are internally coded as integer values:

```
utf8ToInt("red")  #works
utf8ToInt(factor("red")) #does not work
utf8ToInt(1) #does not work
```

To transform the whole dataset you could convert to `matrix`.

```
lapply(as.matrix(df),utf8ToInt)
```

Reading you question: If you want to replace "e" with "E" why don't you simply use regEx?

df

```
       a      b    c1
1    red   blue white
2   blue yellow black
3 yellow    red   red
4  black   pink  blue
```

Then use:

```
df[] <- sapply(as.matrix(df),gsub,pattern="e",replacement="E")

       a      b    c1
1    rEd   bluE whitE
2   bluE yEllow black
3 yEllow    rEd   rEd
4  black   pink  bluE
```

Comment: I used the colors data frame as an example only.  i am specifically interested in how utf8toInt works.  The method used to change E to e was just an exercise.  Thanks for the help.